# I was thinking, if you are/were interested, you could

Tags: conditional-constructions

> I was thinking, if you **are / were** interested, you could come over to dinner tomorrow.

Could someone please tell me if **are** and **were** are both natural here?

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking, if you **are** / **were** interested, you could come over *for* dinner tomorrow.

This is a good question, and a great phrase to boot!
Be mindful that as *dinner* is an event and not a location, *for* sounds more natural.

Both your examples can be used, but in different context:

> We are planning to get together this week.
> I was thinking, if you **are** interested, you could come over for dinner tomorrow.

> I couldn’t fully read your response at the meeting.
> I was thinking, if you **were** interested, you could come over for dinner tomorrow.

**TL;DR**
In other words, **are** is probably most correct, but complex time context can allow for use of **were**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about this, but `were` may sound better.
Or you could say:

> I was wondering if you could come over to dinner tomorrow

Asking whether the other person is interested is somewhat captured in the tone of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the correct answer is "are". If you ARE interested, you could come over to dinner tomorrow. "Were" is conditional and of an abstract idea.

Answer (score 0):

I actually disagree with both @Aaron John Sabu and @Ara because it is an issue of tense. I believe that 'are' would work better because it is in the present tense. Whereas 'were' is in the past tense meaning 'if you were [previously] interested' vs are, the present tense, 'if you are [currently] interested.'